# How can I mount cifs shares in (k)ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: mount, samba, 13.04, cifs, smb

In (k)ubuntu 12.10, I could mount a cifs drive (from my Apple Airport Extreme) with

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=foobar,password=foobar,rw,hard,nosetuids,noperm //192.168.1.2/Drive ~/mnt/mount_point
```

This no longer works after my upgrade to 13.04 today. I now get the error

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I already had `cifs-utils` installed, and installing `smbnetfs` did not help. How can I mount cifs volumes in (k)ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem trying to mount a Apple Time Capsule volume.

I solved by adding a `sec=ntlm` option to /etc/fstab.

For your command, use

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=foobar,password=foobar,rw,hard,nosetuids,noperm,sec=ntlm //192.168.1.2/Drive ~/mnt/mount_point
```

See a more detailed explanation about the root change in:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=81bcd8b795229c70d7244898efe282846e3b14ce

Not sure if this is the best solution because I suppose I'm lowering security.

Comment: I'm actually trying to mount an Apple Airport Extreme, so it's probably a similar issue. The way I understand it, before this upgrade, ntlm was the default. Now ntlmv2 is the default, so by reverting to ntlm it's no worse security than before. Presumably, the Apple products are not capable of ntlmv2.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes. That edit didn't go through. See http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/112619 I understand why you were trying to edit the answer now. Please try to be a little more specific about *why* you're editing and what you're adding next time ;) .

Comment: Okay, apologies for poor communication on my part. I meant to say that this answer does *not* specifically answer my question, although it does point me in the right direction. I attempted to edit the answer so that it *does* answer my question. Also, it seems that askubuntu doesn't notify me for failed edits? That doesn't seem like a great feature either.

Comment: Also, is the best way to respond to reviewers in the comments of the reviewed question or answer?

Comment: +1. I've literally been working on this problem for 2 days. NOTHING worked until this. thank you so much. FYI, working on mounting apple airport extreme disk

Comment: This command hasn't been working for me at this point.  I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and the `user=foobar` option is being rejected.  The syslog says:

    `CIFS VFS: No username specified`

The fix for me was to use `username=foobar` in the options instead of `user=foobar`.