# How can I fix "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE" error when mounting using cifs?

Tags: 13.04, fstab, cifs

I've recently upgraded my station to 13.04 and all mounts I had on `/etc/fstab` stopped working. I can't even mount them at terminal (using `mount -t cifs`) through `smbclient` or nautilus. I always get `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`.

Provided nothing has changed at the server, I assume some configuration has changed in the packages of 13.04. Maybe password encryption, maybe port? I have just spent 10 hours looking for a solution and, since I have a serious time retrain, I am considering rolling back to 12.10. Could someone give a clue where to find it?

Thanks all.

Comment: I found the answer in another topic [[link here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285874/how-can-i-mount-cifs-shares-in-kubuntu-13-04)], using the sec=ntlm option for cifs.mount

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. I found that adding `nounix` as an option in the fstab file allow for the network shares to be accessed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The "My problem now is..." part is a new question. Please use the "Your Answer" section only for actual answers. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. I have removed the question now.